# SVN Working copy ' locked. Clean up too not working

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-update

I was trying to update my SVN folder and then I found conflicts.

With out resolving any conflicts I just closed command propmpt.

From then When ever I am trying to :

```
SVN up
```

Getting th error SVN Working copy ' locked.

Also clean up fails with the following error:

> Cleanup failed ti process the following paths:
>   Working copy is locked

I have also tried deleting the problematic folder and trying svn up. Even this does not help.

Updating the root folder will take a lot of time and do not want that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When this happens to me the only things that helps is clean up on the **root level**. Clean up on any other level doesn't work.